# HOW TO INTEGRATE ME OUTLOOK 2007 & ABOVE IN VB6?

Tags: vb6

I have developed a database (using VB6) for our church and we will like
to add or integrate MS Outlook into the program so that we can use
it for event scheduling, email, appointments etc. etc...

I want to add a command button to the main form so that when a
user clicks on the button, it will open MS Outlook for him/her
to be able to schedule events activities etc....

Thanks so much and hope you can hel me.
Godwin Barnes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this carefully: [Ask].  `How to write this app` type questions are generally too broad.  However, you *can* ask 100 specific questions related to your project as you get stuck along the way.  As is, you seem to be looking for a collaborator.

Comment: `shell "outlook.exe"` will run it, for more integration you need to google for *outlook automation with vb6* E.g. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220595

Answer (score 0):

You could use the shell command as is mentioned above which would start outlook for you.  If you wanted more control from the VB app then you could try CDO but it looks like Microsoft have stopped supporting it after Outlook 2007 (see this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028411/en-us)

There is another article about automating Outlook which could be a good start [automation article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/220595), give that a go and see if it points you in the right direction.